# TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".vue" when run node in ssr.js

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

I use Inertia, Vue3, and Vite as bundling assets. When I set up and run with SSR in nodejs the error always appears Unknown file extension ".vue". I've been googling for days but haven't solved it.

This is my ssr.js file which I run with nodemon

```
import { createSSRApp, h } from 'vue'
import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-renderer'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import createServer from '@inertiajs/server'

createServer.default((page) => createInertiaApp({
  page,
  render: renderToString,
  resolve: async (name) => {
      return (await import(`./Pages/${name}.vue`)).default;
  },
  setup({ app, props, plugin }) {
    return createSSRApp({
      render: () => h(app, props),
    }).use(plugin)
  },
}))
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
// import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.mjs',
        }),
        // react(),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    ssr: {
        noExternal: ['@inertiajs/server'],
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': '/resources/js'
        }
    }
});
```

when I run it with nodemon ssr.js an error like this will appear

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".vue" for C:\Users\USER\Documents\biviplant\biviplant\resources\js\Pages\Test.vue
```

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a while but have you solved this? For this particular issue, we don't need to have ".vue" on there for import to work. 

But I suspect the reason you added it in is the same as mine which is "SSR and Vite is just not working" and we're just trying stuff now?

Comment: if you run nodemon ssr.js you don't use vite